# Prove: $||x|-|y||\leq |x+y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to prove: $||x|-|y||\leq |x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ I have already proved $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$.

I saw proofs for $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$, can I use the proof for  $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$ and just add that $|x-y|\leq|x+y|$?

Comment: No, because $|x - y| \le |x + y|$ is wrong. Apply the inequality you know with $-y$ replacing $y$.

Comment: It's not true that $|x-y|\leq |x+y|$. Try $x=1,y=-1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *I have already proved $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$.*

One may observe that
$$
|x|=|x-y+y|\le |x-y|+|y|
$$ swapping $x$ and $y$ gives
$$
|y|=|y-x+x|\le |y-x|+|x|,
$$ from which one gets
$$
||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|
$$ then making $y \to-y$ we obtain
$$
||x|-|y||\leq |x+y|.
$$

Comment: With this I can get the proof:$ ||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$ but how can I connect it to $|x+y|$?

Comment: @Roby5 Two steps: $||x|-|y||\le |x-y|$. Then set $y=-b$ giving  $||x|-|b||\le |x+b|$

Answer (score 3):

#### Hint: $$||x|-|y||\le |x+y| \Leftrightarrow (||x|-|y||)^2\le (|x+y|)^2$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\left| x \right| =\left| x+y-y \right| \le \left| x+y \right| +\left| y \right| \quad \Rightarrow \left| x \right| -\left| y \right| \le \left| x+y \right| \\ \left| y \right| =\left| y+x-x \right| \le \left| y+x \right| +\left| x \right| \quad \Rightarrow \left| y \right| -\left| x \right| \le \left| x+y \right| $$
combine all together then $$||x|-|y||\leq |x+y|\\ \\ $$

Answer (score 3):

If you already know how to show that $\left||u|-|v|\right|\leq |u-v|$, then let $u=x,v=-y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(\lvert\lvert x\rvert-\lvert y \rvert \rvert)^2 \le (\lvert x + y \rvert)^2$$

$$\lvert x\rvert^2 + \lvert y\rvert^2 - \lvert 2xy\rvert\le x^2+y^2+2xy$$

$$-\lvert xy\rvert \le  xy$$

Which is of course true by the definition of the absolute value